# How can a Spring Webflow application be configured to use Xslt to render its viewstates

Tags: spring-mvc, xslt, spring-webflow-2

I would like my Spring Webflow app to render its views using XSLT. I managed to get a pure Spring MVC app to render with xslt by configuring an XSLTviewresolver and a controller method that returned an already prepared xml as a source.

But I'm not sure how to apply that to the webflow app.
I've added the configuration for the XSLT view resolver and set the view state to the xsl, then  I call the controller method that returns the xml source in the on-render of the view state.So far I only get the xsl back as the output and not the transformed xml or even the raw xml.

**EDIT**
flow.xml-full

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
  <view-state id="messageChoice" view="start1">
   <transition on="chooseA" to="messageA"/>
   <transition on="chooseB" to="messageB"/>
      </view-state> 
      <view-state id="messageA" view="messageA">
       <transition on="start" to="messageChoice"/>
      </view-state> 
      <view-state id="messageB" view="xsltview">
       <on-render>
        <evaluate expression="sampleController.viewXSLT(externalContext.getNativeRequest(),externalContext.getNativeResponse())" result="requestScope.xmlSource"/>
       </on-render>
       <transition on="start" to="messageChoice"/>
      </view-state>
      <end-state id="finish"/>
    </flow>
```

controller-snippet

```
@RequestMapping(value="/viewxslt")
public ModelAndView viewXSLT(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    // builds absolute path of the XML file
    String xmlFile = "/WEB-INF/xml/thexml.xml";
    String contextPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath(xmlFile);
           String xmlFilePath = ""+contextPath + File.separator + xmlFile;
     Source source = new StreamSource(new File(contextPath));
    // adds the XML source file to the model so the XsltView can detect
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("xsltview");
    model.addObject("xmlSource", source);
    return model;
}
```

**EDIT**
flow-config-full

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  <context:annotation-config />
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.genkey.derek" />
  <mvc:view-controller path="/start" />
  <mvc:view-controller path="/messageHome" />
  <mvc:resources location="/" mapping="/resources/**" />
  <faces:resources />
  <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
   <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
   <property name="order" value="3" />
 </bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
<bean id="xsltviewresolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xslt.XsltViewResolver">
 <property name="order" value="1"/>
 <property name="sourceKey" value="xmlSource"/>
 <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xslt.XsltView"/>
 <property name="viewNames">
  <array>
   <value>xsltview</value>
  </array>
 </property>
 <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/xsl/" />
 <property name="suffix" value=".xsl" />
</bean>
<bean id="viewFactoryCreator" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator"> 
 <property name="viewResolvers"> 
  <list> 
   <ref bean="xsltviewresolver"/> 
   <ref bean="faceletsViewResolver" /> 
  </list> 
 </property> 
</bean>
<bean id="faceletsViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.faces.mvc.JsfView"/>
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml" />
  <property name="order">
   <value>2</value>
  </property>
</bean>
 <bean class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter">
  <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
 </bean>
 <webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
  <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
   <webflow:listener ref="facesContextListener"/>
  </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
 </webflow:flow-executor>
 <webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices" >
 <webflow:flow-location  path="WEB-INF/flows/startFlow.xml"/>
 </webflow:flow-registry>
 <faces:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" view-factory-creator="viewFactoryCreator" development="true" />
 <bean id="facesContextListener" class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: In webflow configuration, how did you define view resolvers? Show full flow configuration.

Comment: @Prasad I've added the view resolver

Comment: Ok What did you specify in the view-factory-creator attribute of flow-builder-services configuration?

Comment: @Prasad I didn't set the view-factory-creator attribute..I thought the default  was the MvcViewFactoryCreator..and that would be able to handle integrate with the XSLTviewResolver..feel free to fill in any knowledge gaps too

Comment: Check this: http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/system-setup.html#builder-service-view-factory-creator

Comment: Try by:<bean id="viewFactoryCreator"
  class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator">
  <property name="viewResolvers">
   <list>
    <ref bean="xsltviewresolver"/>
    <ref bean="faceletsViewResolver" />
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>

Comment: @Prasad after inserting your snippet to configure the view-factory-creator the subsequent view-states have stopped rendering and since there are no errors in the log.i'm a bit stumped